# how to change css modal box graphic display width?

Tags: css

I have a picture that, when clicked, opens up a css js modal box of another picture. Right now the box is too small. How do I edit the width of the graphic that appears?

http://www.awastudios.net (click one of the comic book covers)

I tried to edit the css code (app.css) but nothing changes.

```
.creator-modal {
    background:#20212a;
    border:1px solid #3f4150;
    padding:0;
    max-width:700px;
}
@media screen and (max-width:63.99875em) {
    .creator-modal{
        max-width:95%;
        min-height:inherit;
        height:auto;
        margin:auto;
    }
}
.reveal-overlay{
    background-color:rgba(0,0,0,.45);
}
.regular-modal{
    padding:15px;
    font-size:14px;
    background:#20212a;
    border:1px solid #3f4150;
}
```

I changed max-width from 700px to 1500px and 80%, but nothing changes.

I've done a hard refresh on the browser (ctrlF5) but that doesn't help.

Any help would be appreciated! Thank you.

Comment: Have you tried setting the max width of .creator-modal to 100%? You have set it to 700px currently which is restricting you to increase the width of your graphic.

Answer (score 0):

If i understood u , u want make modal more large thats right , add in ur HTMl div class="reveal creator-modal" width:100%

```css
.creator-modal {
    background: #20212a;
    border: 1px solid #3f4150;
    padding: 0;
    max-width: 750px; /* up to 750px */
}
```

```html
<div class="reveal creator-modal" id="fightgirls" data-reveal="" role="dialog" aria-hidden="false" data-yeti-box="fightgirls" data-resize="fightgirls" data-n="xyhm2h-n" style="display: block; top: 37px; width: 100%;" tabindex="-1">
      <img src="assets/img/creators/fightgirls.jpg" alt="Frank Cho">
      <button class="close-button" data-close="" aria-label="Close modal" type="button">
        <span aria-hidden="true">×</span>
      </button>
    </div>
```